# Linux изменить права на группу по умолчанию

Tags: linux

Как в Linux (CentOS 8) изменить права для определённой группу по умолчанию?
То есть при приложение которое создаёт папки и файлы с правами "drwxr-xr-x".
А мне нужно что бы он автоматически их создавал "drwxr**w**xr-x". Вручную постоянно менять так себе занятие...
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Перед выполнением программы в том же шеле ввполните:

```
umask 002
```

Можно эту команду добавить в профиль пользователя если она запускается интерактивно, но это повлияет на поведение всех программ.